# how to hide a layer on ajaxstop in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have done some research about this issue. But all i could find was that IE deprecated some code that is causing this issue.
I am developing an application that 95 % of it  are Ajax calls. Therefore i needed to block the UI. Then i thought why not to use the block UI plug in from jquery. When i implemented it worked like a charm in  FF, Chrome, IE9+ but not in IE 8. I decided to build my own and made it VERY simple using Ajaxtart to show a div and Ajaxstop to hide the div. It works fine on FF  and IE9+ but not in IE 8
I get the following error:
**t.appendChild(e)
SCRIPT65535: Unexpected call to method or property access. 
jquery1.10, line 5 character 25691**
The error is coming frmo the jquery script. I am using jquery 1.10
To show and hide i am soing the following:

```
$( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
    $("#overlay").show();

    });
$( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
    $("#overlay").hide();

    });
```

this is driving me nuts for weeks now. If anybody has any ideas how to fix this  please help me out.
thank you..

Comment: Could you post more of your code?  There could be many possible problems.  For instance, if there's an HTML5 tag in your code that's not recognized by IE8 (without using a shiv) - this is a common problem.

Comment: Howard, all i have is a div with id naned overlsy nothing to complicated. It looks like when the request is don from the ajax call the csll is never killed therefore it does not close the overlay. But on other browsers this does not happen only in IE8. Very weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research found couple articles saying that this is a bug in  IE8. If it is i am not to sure, i guess will try and find more info. For now i have found a work around. i modified the Jquery with the following: 
All i need was to add a try and catch where the error was occurring; therefore the exception would not break the execution of my ajax call.

thank you.

```
try{
t.appendChild(e)
}catch(err)
{
//nothing here.
}
```